# Can't add Developer ribbon in Word 2010?

Tags: microsoft-word-2010

I originally posted this question here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28308686/cant-add-developer-ribbon-in-word-2010

But was directed here, so I'll repost my question:

So I thought I'd enable the Developer ribbon in Word 2010 in order to muck around a bit more.

Got into customize the ribbon, found the developer ribbon checkbox, checked it. Clicked OK.

... nothing ...

What would prevent that? Policy, I assume?

Windows 7.

I'm mostly just curious (I have local admin, so I can nose around on the PC pretty freely). What Policy/setting/etc, would prevent the Developer ribbon from being enabled without any warning/error message? (I get nothing when I click OK .. no message, nothing).

Some additional clarifications:

Excel works fine, I added Developer ribbon in Excel and working fine.
ALT+F11 in Word brings up the VB editor just fine.

I also found reference to this key:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Excel\Options\DeveloperTools = 1
```

and tried to set the matching Word value. 
Still no luck.

Comment: [Try repairing office](https://support.office.microsoft.com/en-us/article/Repair-an-Office-application-7821d4b6-7c1d-4205-aa0e-a6b40c5bb88b?CorrelationId=4e832e13-5a48-4d02-93b8-825f1b9a3233&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US). When you go back to the setting, is it still checked or does it uncheck itself?

Comment: Office 2010: `14.0.4763.1000`
2010 + SP1: `14.0.6029.1000 or later`
2010 + SP2: `14.0.7015.1000 or later`—
which do you have?

Comment: Doing a repair now ... It shows as "14.0.7015.1000" in the program/features.

Comment: Is this at home or in an office / domain environment

Comment: office.  That's why I asked about policies. I'm guessing most likely reason is some policy blocking it? (but why would it allow Excel?) .. and as curiosity/learning, I'd like to understand why/how :)

Comment: Ok repair done. rebooted machine. Checked registry: "DeveloperTools" option is still set to "1" for both Excel and Word. Developer ribbon still there in Excel, still missing in Word. Tried adding it via Options, customize ribbon again .. nothing

Comment: @Techie007: Thanks!  That showed it.  Had to sift through a huge output :) but yep . I see it now, policy on the Word Developer Tool bar is set.  Thank-you! (if you add as an answer, I can accept it :) )

Comment: I stuck it in as an answer. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [GPResult](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490915.aspx) to determine if a policy has been set by your network admin.

If so, ask them to apply a different policy to you.

More info: [Microsoft Office 2010: Manage Microsoft Office with Group Policy](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj631600.aspx)

Comment: Got it .. yeah, I have local admin, so i can "override" it if I need it :) (don't right now, so I'll leave it .).  But I did try it: key is:   software\policies\microsoft\office\14.0\word\options\DeveloperTools  .. set to "0" .. changed it to 1 , viola, Developer ribbon visible.  Thank you kindly!